# How to disable Go button on iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, button, keyboard

Can any one please let me know how to disable the 'Go' button on keyboard?

The purpose is: when the text field is empty Go button has to be disable (gray color) and when type some thing the Go button become active and color blue. (Same as Apple Find iPhone app).

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Interface builder, tick the box which is labelled Auto-enable Return Key.

In code do: `[textField setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES];`

The Return key (Go key) will only be enabled when the text field is not empty.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. But I was unable to find the answer by googling (it is dead easy one).

Comment: "when the text field is empty" - do spaces count as empty? If not, is there a way to add logic to enable the "Go" button only when the text field contains non-whitespace characters?